# What attributive to use to express "clean" in "clean hands"?

Tags: pragmatics

Which attributive: きれい or 清潔 sounds more natural to say "clean hands"?

Comment: Do you mean literally clean, or like "free from guilt/responsibility"?

Comment: Literally clean

Answer (score 1):

清潔 means "being sanitary/hygienic" so I think きれいな手 sounds more like "clean hands."
But, of course, it can mean "pretty hands" by context.